# Can I use jQuery's datepicker on a <td>?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Just like the title says...  I'm wondering if I can assign a datepicker to a td rather than an input tag.  The datepicker should show when you click on the td and clicking on a date should update the contents of the td.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="date" id="date1"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="date" id="date2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  $(".date").each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
  }
</script>
```

What happens currently is that the datepicker div appears in the source but clicking on each td does not trigger it's visibility or content.

As per jQuery's documentation it doesn't look like something that should be possible but I'm curious to know if anyone else has tried it and been successful.

I'm working on some inline editing and for aesthetic reasons I'd prefer to not have to switch the content of the td to an input onclick before triggering the datepicker, updating the input, hiding the input and updating the content of the td with the value of the input etc. etc.

Comment: Why not place `<input>`s inside your `<td>`s?

Comment: Yeah I've been thinking about it since posting the question and I guess I can just style the input to not look like an input.

Comment: I have a td with contenteditable="true", and with a class="datepicker", and the calendar widget is popping up when I click in the innerText. So, datepicker is showing me no love in a TD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DatePicker()](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) - The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field. Focus on the input (click, or use the tab key) to open an interactive calendar in a small overlay.

It is compulsory to be input field to bind a datepicker. So you cannot have datepicker for `td` element. But you can bind datepicker for input field which is inside `td` element.

Comment: Thanks Bhushan.  I was hoping there was a way around it without having to switch all my td's to inputs but looks like I'll just have to get creative with CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do so, but yeah in future you may find it.