# jqueryUI datepicker in wrong cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed a strange behavior in my table. I populate a table from JSON data, each row contains 3 cells. A checkbox followed by two data cells. This works like charm. Further I added the default jQueryUI datepicker, which should appear if the last cell is clicked. But instead the last cell the datepicker appears if the checkbox at the row beginning is clicked.

Any idea why?

```js
var dates = [
  {
                "reason": "Date 1",
                "date": "01.01.2021"
            },
            {
                "reason": "Date 2",
                "date": "04.04.2021"
            },
            {
                "reason": "Date 3",
                "date": "08.08.2021"
            },
            {
                "reason": "Date 4",
                "date": "12.12.2021"
            }
]

 var table = document.getElementById("date-table")

createDateTable(dates)

function createDateTable(dates) {
       table.innerHTML = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            dateRow =   `<tr id="row-${i}">
                            <td><input type=checkbox></td>
                            <td contenteditable='true'>${dates[i].reason}</td>
                            <td>${dates[i].date}</td>
                        </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += dateRow
        }


        $("#date-table tr").each(function () {
            $(this).find("td :last").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true
            })
        })
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="date-table">
        <tbody>
            <!-- filled by script -->
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet ? use tools `[<>]` into your question.

Comment: @DarkBee yes but work with the checkbox and that's the first td.

Comment: @DarkBee which is want I want, the last cell(td) should execute the datepicker. But the code above, executes the datepicker if the checkbox was clicked.

Comment: You have a space inbetween `td` and `:last` meaning it will select the *last element inside the td*. You would need to remove the space **but** you can't bind the jquery datepicker to a `td`. It does require an input. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869744/can-i-use-jquerys-datepicker-on-a-td)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `input` to make it work like:

```js
var dates = [{
    "reason": "Date 1",
    "date": "01.01.2021"
  },
  {
    "reason": "Date 2",
    "date": "04.04.2021"
  },
  {
    "reason": "Date 3",
    "date": "08.08.2021"
  },
  {
    "reason": "Date 4",
    "date": "12.12.2021"
  }
]

var table = document.getElementById("date-table")

createDateTable(dates)

function createDateTable(dates) {
  table.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    dateRow = `<tr id="row-${i}">
                            <td><input type=checkbox></td>
                            <td contenteditable='true'>${dates[i].reason}</td>
                            <td><input type='text' class='datapickerme' value='${dates[i].date}'></td>
                        </tr>`
    table.innerHTML += dateRow
  }

  $('.datapickerme').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true
  });

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="date-table">
    <tbody>
      <!-- filled by script -->
    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

And i use `class` instead of find the last `td`.